# Cause of gearbox bearing issue?

Tags: transmission

I took my Fiat Punto Evo 1.2 2011 to the garage today as it had started making a noise recently and have been quoted £630 for a reconditioned gear box as there is an issue with the gearbox bearings.

Does anyone know what the cause of this could be?

And does this seem a reasonable price? I’m considering trading it in as I was planning to sell it in a couple of months anyway and I’m not sure a repair of that price is worth it?

Just want some opinions really...thanks

Comment: Are you asking what else could be making the noise, or why bearings would cause that noise? If you're looking for a second opinion there isn't enough information, like what the mileage is, or where the noise is coming from. What does the noise sound like, does it get louder or higher pitched the faster you get, or you only hear it when in one particular gear?

Comment: Whilst this site isn't for price assistance or shopping advice, I'd first ask the workshop to change the oil in the gearbox.  If the noise persists, consider a good second-hand unit if you're selling the car.

Answer (score 0):

If the transmission is failing due to bearing issues then £600+ sounds like a good price for a recon transmission. I used to work for Nissan UK and did hundreds of transmission rebuilds as Nissan had problems with them (mainy diff bearings) in the Nissan T12 Bluebird era. I think back then a tranny rebuild was around £500 and a recon would have been similar.

As for the cause.. A gearbox is a pretty robust piece of kit, and unless it has been poorly treated.. e.g, not serviced/adjusted/lubricated properly, or the clutch has been dropped harshly over and over with many rough gear changes thrown in, it should last the lifetime of the vehicle. Either that or their is an inherent problem with the likes of bearing quality or assembly proceedures creating an issue. 
Normally bearing problems will just be innitially noticed as a slight whine or rumble, but over time it may get worse untill eventually you'll have a heavier whine or rumbling sound depending on which bearings are failing. 
It should not be ignored though as bearings can and do completely fail, and if this happens it can result in a breakdown at best, or at worst having the gearbox literally turn its insides into a scrap bin.